# How to simulate content and usage

Tags: content, testing, site-usage

I need to test some webparts in an Sharepoint site that has more than a few users, with several documents and usage data (creations, accesses, modifications).

Is there a way to simulate that? Or some place to download a "mockup" SP site with these caracteristics?

I need to replicate what could be a real-world SP corporate site. How would you do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Microsoft has a fully populated Constoso SharePoint site with documents, list entries subsites, user profiles, etc., though I'm not certain where that is available.  I found [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27417) while searching for it which looks promising but I would not swear this is it.

Comment: Great, this is a good start. Thank you. I'll search for this Contoso Sharepoint. The only thing is that I just find an HyperV VM... and I'm already using a Cloudshare VM... Maybe the can install it for me.. Anyway, thanks man.